# Left volunteer role reason

Tags: volunteering

I'm going for a few interviews. I can justify why I'm leaving my current place but I can't really think of a good professional way of saying why I left my volunteer role after 7 years.

The real reason I left is because membership decreased. I was creating a website for the members and no one used it anymore so it was a bit demotivating. They also wanted me to do loads with little gratitude since it was for free I left.

I'm worried if I say the truth in the interview they will think oh he only has motivation for big stuff and create sites for million of users.

What do you suggest,
Thanks

Comment: Do I understand this right that you worked as an unpaid volunteer for seven years? Saying "I need to earn some money" would be a good reason.

Comment: I suppose but it was mainly a weekend thing. If the employee talked to them they might find out.

Answer (score 3):

> Membership was steadily declining so there wasn't much left for me to do.

It's as simple as that and really, I doubt anyone will even ask. Volunteer roles aren't subject to the same kind of scrutiny as your actual work history. If it comes up in conversation they might ask given how long you've been with that organisation. You can phrase it however you like but even a boilerplate reason like "*I felt like it was time to move on*" or "*I didn't have the free time to dedicate to that position*" would work.

Comment: Yes, you didn't quit a job, you just stopped volunteering.

Comment: And if you are leaving a full time volunteer position to seek paid work, that is reason enough by itself.